# The Achievement Drawer does not highlight on new net rep

Tags: bug

This started for me, and apparently others, today.  A user gets a new badge or a net-positive change in reputation, and the drawer icon does not change like it used to.

When I say drawer icon, I mean...

[image]

I am using Windows 10, Firefox 43.0.2

At 20:30 UTC today, net positive rep triggered the drawer icon to highlight.  This may have been an anomaly.

Comment: If it's *only* badges, those can take a long time to appear, sometimes as long as several hours.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I have not actually experienced badges, just net rep.  I mentioned this in chat, and that is another thing someone mentioned.

Comment: Seems better now, for me. Most-recent badge did light up the drawer. (Though that "Disciplined" one never did show up in the "achievements" list.)

Comment: No issues with Win8.1 & Chrome.

Comment: As of January 8th 2016, this issue has not reoccurred.

Answer (score 1):

I was one who mentioned badges. I picked up "Disciplined" 8 hours ago: it shows up in [my activity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/23970/nitsua60) but never lit up my drawer. Then again, it's not listed in today's achievements, either, so perhaps I've just never noticed how long a lag there sometimes is.